# Python 3.9 MetaClass Property vs Classmethod Property

Tags: python, properties, metaclass, python-3.9

Consider the following code

```py
from abc import ABC, ABCMeta


class MyMetaClass(ABCMeta):
    @property
    def metaclass_property(cls):
        return "result"

    # def __dir__(cls):
    #     return list(super().__dir__()) + ['metaclass_property']


class MyBaseClass(ABC, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    @classmethod
    @property
    def baseclass_property(cls):
        return "result"


class MyClass(MyBaseClass, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    pass


assert MyClass.baseclass_property == "result"
assert hasattr(MyClass, 'baseclass_property')
assert 'baseclass_property' in dir(MyClass)

assert MyClass.metaclass_property == "result"
assert hasattr(MyClass, 'metaclass_property')
assert 'metaclass_property' in dir(MyClass)
```

I noticed that this throws an assertion error on the last line. (python v3.9.6). Why is that? Is it a bug? It can be fixed by manually adding it to `__dir__` as per the two uncommented lines.

My question is, what is the best way to resolve this? Is there any fundamental difference between a classmethod property or a metaclass property? (I.e. are there any things that I can or cannot do in one but not the other?) If not, which one should I preferably use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with properties, metaclasses or `abc`.

A simple example:

```py
>>> int.__mro__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> isinstance(int, type)
True
>>> '__mro__' in dir(int)
False
>>> '__mro__' in dir(type)
True
```

In this example, `object` is the base class of `int`, while `type` is the metaclass of `int`.

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) of the `dir` function explicitly says that it

> attempts to produce the most relevant, rather than complete, information

and

> If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.

and

> metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class